# Automatically keeping headings next to their content (or: No headings at the end of pages)

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

The following is a screenshot of a Word 2013 document.

[image]

The highlighted section exhibits a section: heading plus content.

This section has been split by a page break. It is possible to fix this by selecting the whole section, clicking on **Paragraph** and checking the box **"Keep with next"**.

Nonetheless, some documents have dozens of sections. Correcting them all one by one is burdensome.

Is there a way to automatically prevent all headings to be separated from their contents by page breaks?

Comment: Change the default heading style?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make "Keep with Next" part of your style for all headings.

You can edit a style by right-clicking it in the *Styles* area of the *Home* tab and clicking **Modify**. (If the style doesn't show up in that list, click the little "expand" arrow in the *Styles* area. Then, click the **Manage Styles** icon in the pop-up window that appears and select the style from that list.)

Once you've got the *Modify Style* window open, click the **Format** button and select **Paragraph.** In the *Paragraphs* window, click the **Line and Page Breaks** tab. Check **Keep with Next** and click **OK.**

If your heading styles are based on other styles, you may only need to do this once. (For example, if Heading 2 is based on Heading 1, changes to Heading 1 will automatically update Heading 2.) You can see what style, if any, a style is based on in the *Modify Style* window. If your headings aren't all based on a common style, you'll need to repeat this process for each heading.